# ¿Cómo hacer una línea de tarjetas en html?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css-grid-layout

Tengo 3 tarjetas alineadas de forma horizontal, y quiero agregar otras 3, el problema es que se agregan las 3 justo al lado de las 3 anteriores, quedando 6 en la misma línea, como puedo hacer para tener 2 líneas horizontales con 3 tarjetas cada línea? Me recomendaron usar bootstrap grid, pero en este caso no sabría cómo implementarlo. Adjunto código y fotos.

Index:

```
<div class="title-cards">
        <h2>Selecciona una asignatura</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="title-cards">
        <h3>1er Año</h3>
        <h3>1er y 2do Bimestre</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="container-card">
    
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/Evangelios.jpg">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido-card">
            <h3>Evangelios</h3>
            <p>Portal de tareas de Evangelios</p>
            <a href="#">Acceder</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/Homilética.jpg">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido-card">
            <h3>Homilética I</h3>
            <p>Portal de tareas de Homilética I</p>
            <a href="#">Acceder</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/Testamento.jpg">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido-card col-4">
            <h3>Introducción al Antiguo Testamento</h3>
            <p>Portal de tareas de Introducción al Antiguo Testamento</p>
            <a href="#">Acceder</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
/*Cards*/
.container-card{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}
.title-cards{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
.card{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: all 400ms ease-out;
    cursor: default;
}


.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    transform: translateY(-3%);
}
.card img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 210px;
}
.card .contenido-card{
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.card .contenido-card h3{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
}
.card .contenido-card p{
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #6a6a6a;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.card .contenido-card a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2fb4cc;
    border: 1px solid #2fb4cc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.card .contenido-card a:hover{
    background: #2fb4cc;
    color: #fff;
}


.flex-container {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:768px){
    .container-card1{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .card1{
        margin: 15px;
    }
}
/*Fin-Cards*/
```

[image: Index]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que quieres algo asi:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
/*Cards*/
.container-card{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}
.title-cards{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
.card{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: all 400ms ease-out;
    cursor: default;
}


.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    transform: translateY(-3%);
}
.card img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 210px;
}
.card .contenido-card{
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.card .contenido-card h3{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
}
.card .contenido-card p{
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #6a6a6a;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.card .contenido-card a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2fb4cc;
    border: 1px solid #2fb4cc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.card .contenido-card a:hover{
    background: #2fb4cc;
    color: #fff;
}


.flex-container {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:768px){
    .container-card1{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .card1{
        margin: 15px;
    }
}
/*Fin-Cards*/
```

```html
<div class="title-cards">
      <h2>Selecciona una asignatura</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="title-cards">
      <h3>1er Año</h3>
      <h3>1er y 2do Bimestre</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="container-card">

  <div class="card">
    <figure>
      <img src="images/Evangelios.jpg">
    </figure>
    <div class="contenido-card">
      <h3>Evangelios</h3>
      <p>Portal de tareas de Evangelios</p>
      <a href="#">Acceder</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <figure>
      <img src="images/Homilética.jpg">
    </figure>
    <div class="contenido-card">
      <h3>Homilética I</h3>
      <p>Portal de tareas de Homilética I</p>
      <a href="#">Acceder</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <figure>
      <img src="images/Testamento.jpg">
    </figure>
    <div class="contenido-card col-4">
      <h3>Introducción al Antiguo Testamento</h3>
      <p>Portal de tareas de Introducción al Antiguo Testamento</p>
      <a href="#">Acceder</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-card">

  <div class="card">
    <figure>
      <img src="images/Evangelios.jpg">
    </figure>
    <div class="contenido-card">
      <h3>Evangelios</h3>
      <p>Portal de tareas de Evangelios</p>
      <a href="#">Acceder</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <figure>
      <img src="images/Homilética.jpg">
    </figure>
    <div class="contenido-card">
      <h3>Homilética I</h3>
      <p>Portal de tareas de Homilética I</p>
      <a href="#">Acceder</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <figure>
      <img src="images/Testamento.jpg">
    </figure>
    <div class="contenido-card col-4">
      <h3>Introducción al Antiguo Testamento</h3>
      <p>Portal de tareas de Introducción al Antiguo Testamento</p>
      <a href="#">Acceder</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Olvidaste cerrar `<div class="container-card">`

Comment: Funcionó! Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Me alegro, no olvides marcar la respuesta como 'Correcta' para así cerrar la pregunta. Saludos!